# Select não seleciona o valor correto

Tags: java, html, html-select, jstl, foreach-jstl

Estou com o seguinte problema:

```
<select name="cargo" id="selectCargo" 
    class="form-control show-tick maiuscula" required >
    <option value="">ESCOLHA A EMPRESA</option>
    <c:forEach items="${filaEmpresa }" var = "filaEmpresa">
        <option value="${filaEmpresa.id}" 
            selected="${funcionario.empresa.id }">${filaEmpresa.id }
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Esse meu `select`, não esta selecionando corretamente o `ID` da empresa do funcionário.

**Ex**: o `ID` é 7 e ele ta selecionando sempre o 10 (que é o último).

Sempre esta selecionando o último valor, mesmo que no `funcionario.empresa.id` esteja o valor correto.

Já debuguei e não encontrei o ponto do erro.

Nesse caso eu estou realizando a alteração de um funcionário. Mas esse é o único campo que não esta correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O atributo `selected` é um valor booleano que indica qual das opções deve ser selecionada. Caso haja múltiplas tags `option` com a propriedade `selected`, a última será selecionada.

Como você quer selecionar a empresa do funcionário, você deve verificar se o identificador da `empresa` e do `funcionario.empresa` são iguais. Caso sejam, você deve adicionar a propriedade `selected`. Exemplo:

```
<select name="cargo" id="selectCargo" class="form-control show-tick maiuscula" required>
    <option value="">ESCOLHA A EMPRESA</option>
    <c:forEach items="${filaEmpresa}" var="empresa">
        <option value="${empresa.id}" <c:out value="${funcionario.empresa.id eq empresa.id ? 'selected' : ''}"></c:out>>${empresa.id}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ótima explicação :D

Answer (score 0):

O `selected` não recebe valores, ele serve para "setar" o option default, a cada laço rodado no forEach ele printa o `selected` na option, sendo assim sempre vai ficar o ultimo selecionado mesmo. Para que funcione da forma que quer, terá que fazer uma condicional e escrever o `selected` somente na `option` que deve ficar mesmo selecionada...